# wso2 API Manager upgrade to 2.1

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have been using the combination of WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 and WSO2 Idenity server 5.2.0
The configurations was based on https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

Now for the socket API support , have to upgrade API Manager to 2.1.0.

We are using not much features other than API management in API manager and user storing in Identity server.

Is there a chance to avoid migration in total and set up newwer versions and migrate the API's and users alone . The benefit is the installation will be fresh and will have existing data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need move the existing data to the newer version, then you must follow the migration guide. 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 migration is fairely simple. For IS migration, you can follow "[Configuring WSO2 Identity Server as a Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager)" documentation and setup IS 5.3.0 as the Key Manager. Here make sure to point to existing databases which were used in IS 5.2.

Comment: I was hoping if there is any importing/exporting tools for users and API's ,that wud have been simpler.

Comment: API import/export tool available will only move the API metadata and it doesn't move any user data or subscription related data.

Comment: My main data is User Data. API/Subscritpion data is less importance in my scenario.Is there  a chance to migrate data?

Comment: If i can migrate user data ; I can set the new wso2  and work with it. I can avoid the whole environment migration.. Is there a way to migrate user data?I am using WSO2 Identity server as key manager